# some days I cannot create new sites anymore (admin too)

Tags: error

I am not totaly new but a beginner in SharePoint 2010. I had to take the responsability and we did the migration from 2007 to 2010. It worked.

Here the facts: Win Server 2008 R2 (virtual) SP2010, MSSQL 2008 on another server (hardware), Nintex Workflow (one single wf yet) for a form which works very linear and this worked too, one server farm and one site collection. We use a masterpage which was created for us (it worked almost two months now.
All authors have only "Approvers" rights. They cannot create new sites.

Now on January the new reorganization structure starts and I had to redesign the organization part. I had some sites to create and that worked fine. at the evening I left and when I cam the next morning I couldn't make new sites and also the NINTEX WOrkflow don't start anymore. In addiation when I create new "document" lists I get an error message but it creates the new list.
I probably did something but I don't know what. I think I did all time the same to create a site, edit a page or copy content to another page etc.

**The eror message is** (engl. translation  below): 
Fehler 
Der Benutzer kann nicht gefunden werden. 
Führen Sie die Problembehandlung mit Microsoft SharePoint Foundation aus. 
Korrelations-ID: cc7cfb3c-555c-466a-b2ed-217d0089d712 
Datum und Uhrzeit: 21.12.2011 08:46:42

**ENGL** (my translation): ;-)
error
the user cannot be found
start the troubleshooting with MS Foundation...
Correlation-ID: cc7cfb3c-555c-466a-b2ed-217d0089d712

**Here a small output from the logfile:**
12/21/2011 08:52:19.02  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x17E4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         af74    Medium      HTTP request URL: /Data_in/msg_truecolor.gif    f9ccd527-a001-4e93-96b2-48f78e6e0e6a
12/21/2011 08:52:19.03  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x12D4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:XXXX.gif)). Execution Time=8.18064865786015   f9ccd527-a001-4e93-96b2-48f78e6e0e6a
12/21/2011 08:52:19.03  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x1754  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:XXXX.gif))
12/21/2011 08:52:19.03  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x1754  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:XXXX.gif) d4c3fe52-7e42-4822-8e74-2daead0cd817
12/21/2011 08:52:19.03  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x1CDC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         af71    Medium      HTTP Request method: GET    d4c3fe52-7e42-4822-8e74-2daead0cd817
12/21/2011 08:52:19.03  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x1CDC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         af75    Medium      Overridden HTTP request method: GET d4c3fe52-7e42-4822-8e74-2daead0cd817
12/21/2011 08:52:19.03  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x1CDC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         af74    Medium      HTTP request URL: /Data_in/radar.gif    d4c3fe52-7e42-4822-8e74-2daead0cd817
12/21/2011 08:52:19.03  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:URL.gif)). Execution Time=8.1510359556871 d4c3fe52-7e42-4822-8e74-2daead0cd817
12/21/2011 08:52:21.39  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:URL%3DFalse))
12/21/2011 08:52:21.39  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (POST:URL%3DFalse) 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.39  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.42  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.47  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           Fields                          88y1    Medium      No document templates uploaded for list "$Resources:core,MasterPageGallery;" -- none found for list template "100". 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.69  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Creating Web alpha). Execution Time=257.4410993576 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.70  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         85m6    Medium      Applying web template 'CMSPUBLISHING#0' on web url 'URL/alpha'  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.70  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         85m7    Medium      Actual web template to apply to Url 'URL/alpha' is 'CMSPUBLISHING#0'    62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.70  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72h7    Medium      Applying template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" to web at URL "URL/alpha".  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.72  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8l1c    Medium      Preparing 21 features for activation    62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.72  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8l1d    Medium      Feature Activation: Batch Activating Features at URL URL/alpha 'CustomList' (ID: '00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100'), 'DocumentLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101'), 'PictureLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109'), 'TasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107'), 'WorkflowHistoryList' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140'), 'NoCodeWorkflowLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117'), 'AnnouncementsList' (ID: '00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104'), 'ContactsList' (ID: '00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105'), 'DataSourceLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110'), 'DiscussionsList' (ID: '00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108'), 'EventsList' (ID: '00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106'), 'Extern... 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.72* w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8l1d    Medium      ...alList' (ID: '00bfea71-9549-43f8-b978-e47e54a10600'), 'GanttTasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119'), 'GridList' (ID: '00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120'), 'IssuesList' (ID: '00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100'), 'LinksList' (ID: '00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103'), 'SurveysList' (ID: '00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102'), 'WebPageLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18'), 'workflowProcessList' (ID: '00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a'), 'XmlFormLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115'), 'TeamCollab' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5'), .    62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8l1f    Medium      Feature Activation: Batch Activated Features at URL URL/alpha 'CustomList' (ID: '00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100'), 'DocumentLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101'), 'PictureLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109'), 'TasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107'), 'WorkflowHistoryList' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140'), 'NoCodeWorkflowLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117'), 'AnnouncementsList' (ID: '00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104'), 'ContactsList' (ID: '00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105'), 'DataSourceLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110'), 'DiscussionsList' (ID: '00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108'), 'EventsList' (ID: '00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106'), 'Externa... 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75* w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8l1f    Medium      ...lList' (ID: '00bfea71-9549-43f8-b978-e47e54a10600'), 'GanttTasksList' (ID: '00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119'), 'GridList' (ID: '00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120'), 'IssuesList' (ID: '00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100'), 'LinksList' (ID: '00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103'), 'SurveysList' (ID: '00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102'), 'WebPageLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18'), 'workflowProcessList' (ID: '00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a'), 'XmlFormLibrary' (ID: '00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115'), 'TeamCollab' (ID: '00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5'), . 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         88jb    Medium      Feature Activation: Activating Feature 'Publishing' (ID: '22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416') at URL URL/alpha.  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         75fb    Medium      Calling 'FeatureActivated' method of SPFeatureReceiver for Feature 'Publishing' (ID: '22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416').   62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         1ght    High        Publishing Feature activation event handled.    62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         8tsv    Medium      AreaProvisioner.Provision() called with with chromeUrl = '', welcomePageUrl = 'Seiten/default.aspx', availableWebTemplates = '', availablePageLayouts = '', defaultPageLayout = 'null', newPageUrlToken = 'null', themedCssFolderUrl = , alternateCssUrl == null, versioningOnPages = MajorAndMinor, versioningOnDocuments = Major, versioningOnImages = Major, enableModerationOnPages = False, enableModerationOnDocuments = False, enableModerationOnImages = False, enableApprovalWorkflowOnPages = False, enableApprovalWorkflowOnDocuments = False, enableApprovalWorkflowOnImages = False, requireCheckoutOnPages = True, requireCheckoutOnDocuments = False, requireCheckoutOnImages = False, enableSchedulingOnPages = False, enableSchedulingOnDocuments = False, enableSchedulingOnImages = False, allowSpacesInNewPa... 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75* w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         8tsv    Medium      ...geName = False.  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         6wz8    Medium      Adding list Url='WorkflowTasks', Title='$Resources:cmscore,ListNameWorkflowTasks;' for feature Id='00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107'    62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y3    High        Failed to open the file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\cmscore.de-CH.resx'. 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y4    High        #20015: Cannot open "": no such file or folder. 62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y4    High        (#2: Cannot open "": no such file or folder.)   62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y9    High        Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\cmscore.de-CH.resx" from feature id "(null)".   62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e26    Medium      Failed to open the language resource keyfile cmscore.   62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72k4    Medium      0x80070002  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d
12/21/2011 08:52:21.75  w3wp.exe (0x1618)                           0x102C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High        0x80070002  62e895e2-2345-4de9-b69e-a91a42262d8d

I hope that helps you to see what happens.

I would be so happy due to (as a beginner) I am searching a long time and I cannot understand it due to to few knowhow yet.

Thank you very much in advance.
Joel

Comment: How did you go? Did you resolve the issues?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed your Active Directory structure by any chance? That may be causing issues where SharePoint cannot find users expecting a different structure.

The other part of the logs are Nintex Workflow specific and the error may be caused by Nintex and is preventing execution.

Check your Application event logs for Nintex errors at the same time too.

Try to run the command as a farm administrator (if you havent already) to confirm/rule out if it is permissions related.

Update:
There also appears to be a fair number of critical files reported missing in the logs, including the language packs.  Can you confirm your language pack is installed correctly and nothing has changed?

Comment: I tried it also as farmadmin with the same result.

Comment: Did you find anything in the event logs?  The ULS logs (above) look like Nintex threw a wobbly.

Comment: I found two thing which I cannot understand...

Comment: 1.)Object Cache: The super user account utilized by the cache is not configured. This can increase the number of cache misses...

Comment: Is there apossib. here to write more?2. Event log message was: 'Fehler beim Erstellen der Bibliothek 'Seiten'.'. Exception was: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Der Benutzer kann nicht gefunden werden.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.get_Item(String loginName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowNoCodeSupport.LoadWorkflowBytesElevated(SPFile file, Int32 fileVer, Int32& userid, DateTime& lastModified)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.AddDeclSiteTemplates(SPWeb web, String visibility, SPWorkflowTemplateColl......

Comment: Have you restarted IIS (the web server)?

Comment: Yeap, I restartet it a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the disk free space on the SQL Server environment. When that runs too low, all sorts of weird errors (like this one) crop up when you try to create content. This could explain the symptoms you describe here:

> when I cam the next morning I couldn't make new sites and also the
>   NINTEX WOrkflow don't start anymore. In addiation when I create new
>   "document" lists I get an error message but it creates the new list. I
>   probably did something but I don't know what. I think I did all time
>   the same to create a site, edit a page or copy content to another page
>   etc.